# NHibernate how to join to table twice in HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

```
public class Case
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployerIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Case Case { get; set; }
}
```

There is a one to one releationship between Case and Employee.  However there are multiple records in the DB that represent the same Employee.  To find those records we look at the EmployerIdentifier.  So if I have only the Employee.Id how can I write an NHibernate query that returns all the cases for that Employee.  In SQL I would do it by joining to the employee table twice (see example below).

```
Declare @TargetEmployeeID bigint
set @TargetEmployeeID = 246834
select * from Cases C
inner join Employees E on E.EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
inner join Employees EST on EST.EmployerIdentifier = E.EmployerIdentifier
where EST.EmployeeID = @TargetEmployeeID
```

How would I do this using HQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following logic.

Use an in memory query - IQueryable.

Your first query will be to identify the list of Employees that are common between Employee and EmployeeIdentifier entities. This will be an in memory query.

```
var caseList = new IList<Case>();

IQueryable<EmployeeIdentifier> empIdenList =  Persister.Session.Query<EmployeeIdentifier>().Where(ei => ei.EmployeeId = 246834);

caseList = Persister.Session.Query<Case>().Where(e => empIdenList.Contains(e.Employee)).ToList<Case>();
```

Note - We do the ToList() call only in the 2nd query and this is when the query actually gets generated. You could use NHIbernate Profiler to see the actual SQL that gets generated back.

Refer to NHibernate.Linq DLL to find more about Query().

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple in HQL. Try this:

`SELECT Case c INNER JOIN FETCH c.Employee WHERE c.Employee.EmployerIdentifier=:employerId`

If I remember right, though, this will bypass lazy loading if that's something you're concerned with.

Comment: This doesn’t achieve what I was looking for.  Note in the above sql I have to join twice to the employee table.  To do it the way you suggest I would need to have the EmployeeIdentifier but I don't have that initially.  I could make a round trip to the DB to get it but I was trying to avoid that.